# How to copy multiple items to clipboard history in c#?

Tags: c#, .net-core, uwp, windows-runtime, clipboarddata

I'm using the clipboard class from Win API (`Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.Clipboard`). When I try to copy multiple items one by one to the clipboard history, it gets overwritten by the recent item. I want to store every item I copy onto the clipboard history. My clipboard history is enabled and I tried using all of the set methods from clipboard including the `SetText` method from (`System.Windows.Clipboard`) and all of which overwrites instead of adding to history.

```
    private void UpdateClipboardOnProfileDropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.ClearHistory();
        using (var db = new LiteDatabase(Path.Combine(documents, "Auto Paste Clipboard", "data.db")))
        {
            var collection = db.GetCollection<ClipboardProfile>("clipboard");

            var clipboard = collection.FindOne(x => x.Profile == ProfileComboBox.Text);

            clipboard.Clipboard.Reverse();

            MessageBox.Show(clipboard.Clipboard.Count.ToString());
            foreach (var item in clipboard.Clipboard)
            {
                DataPackage data = new DataPackage
                {
                    RequestedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy
                };

                data.SetText(item);                          
                Clipboard.SetContent(data);
            }                                
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It takes some delays for **Clipboard** history to save the current item. Therefore, you could try to add a delay when an item is added.

Please check the following code as a sample:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if(Clipboard.IsHistoryEnabled())
    {
        List<string> lists=new List<string>{ "1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10"}; 
        foreach(var item in lists)
        {
            DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
            dataPackage.SetText(item);
            Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
            await Task.Delay(250);
        }
    }
}
```

Note, if these items are not all added, you could increase the delay time.

Comment: Thank you. It similarly helped me in copying multiple items, using python's `pyperclip` module.

Comment: I Found this after wondering where half my clipboard items went, and I just wanted to say that, while this solution works, it kinda stinks, doesn't it? :D

Is there really no way for Windows to buffer these SetContent requests? I'm trying to add an Image and a URL to the history and adding an artifical delay just makes things sluggish.

Not to mention that I don't even know if my delay will always be long enough.